# How to get a high resolution image of the material preview?

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

How can I create a simple scene setup that looks like material preview? I want to render the material preview (specifically the flat XY plane) in a higher resolution. I've tried to copy the setup in a Blender scene, but it doesn't look the same. Are there any addons or ways to export the material preview in any resolution?

**Note that I need it to look exactly the same as the material preview.**

Comment: Not sure how to get the scene, but you could increase the DPI in *User preferences > System* and take a screenshot. You can also zoom in on the preview by pressing and holding Ctrl MMB and sliding the cursor.

Comment: You can also make it full screen by pressing Ctrl+Up arrow over the panel. [Here is the result](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/63435) of combining all these zooming methods.

Comment: @gandalf3 can you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can adjust the DPI, zoom in, and full screen the *Materials* panel to make it bigger, then take a screenshot.

- Make the *Properties editor* full screen by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>
- Increase the *DPI* in *User preferences > System*
- Zoom in on the panel by holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>MMB</kbd> and dragging the cursor

**Result:** (click for full size)

[image: Screenshot of preview]

The obvious limitation being that you can't go larger than the maximum zoom, or larger than your monitor.

## Get the blend:

Alternatively, you can download the blendfile from the [GIT repo with your browser via Phabricator](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/):

- [Blender Internal preview file](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/preview.blend)
- [Cycles preview file](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/preview_cycles.blend)

To download a file, go to the link above and click *Download raw file* on the right:

[image]

Then click *Download*:

[image]

The different preview scenes are on the following layers:

**Layer 1:** *Flat XY plane*

**Layer 2:** *Sphere*

**Layer 3:** *Cube*

**Layer 4:** *Suzanne (Monkey)*

**Layer 5:** *World Sphere*

**Layer 11:** (the first layer on the second row) *Hair*