# Default lightning, or how to adjust materials properties correctly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, scene, lighting

**Situation:**
I always adjust my materials by hdri environment map. This method work well for me. But what if I want to share my materials, or sell it? 
I search for some default lightning setup and I found [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5227/how-to-get-a-high-resolution-image-of-the-material-preview) with [link](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/datafiles/preview_cycles.blend) to *default scene* used for material preview in material panel.

**Problem:**
When I adjust my material by this *default scene*, material looks too bright in *hdri lighted* scenes, just because this *default material scene* has low lightning compared to *hdri lighted* scene.

**Question:**
Is there some general standard how to "calibrating" materials?

Comment: Red car paint will look brighter under a sunny day then at night, materials don't change according to lighting conditions. Even if they did you couldn't possibly adjust a material to fit every conceivable scene setup one might come up with. If it's too bright you adjust exposure or film, not colors.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos How I can correct it by exposure, when I have different materials from different sources, which was created under different lightning conditions? So some of them are brighten, some are darker. This is also about colors, because creators set colors "wrong" in effort to achieve right colors in "wrong" lighting scene. It looks there is no "default" light setup. And this is the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution in "Cycles Encyclopedia" written by Blender certified trainers Frederic Steinmetz and Gottfried Hofmann. (Available on blender store or blendermarket.) Authors use [this "Blender Material Preview Scene"](http://blenderdiplom.com/en/downloads/584-download-cycles-material-test-scene.html) by Robìn Marin. So I thing this can be considered as default scene for Cycles material settings.

Comment: If this answers your question (I presume it does since it's your answer) you should mark it as the accepted solution (click the icon on the left).